# Add delay before .hide() w/jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a simple code that keeps an element visible while a mouse hovers over it and hides it once the mouse is out.:

```
$(".item").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).show();
    }, 
    function () {
        $(this).hide();
    }                       
);
```

I would like to add some delay before it hides, but adding `$(this).delay(500).hide();`does not seem to work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var my_timer;
$(".item").hover(
    function () {
        clearTimeout(my_timer);
        $(this).show();
    }, 
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.hide();
        }, 500);
    }                       
);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e3cNK/1/

If you want to be able to re-show the element after it has been hidden then you want to change the opacity of the element rather than changing its `display` to `none`. This will keep the elements in the regular flow of the page so when the user mouse-overs the hidden element it can show again:

```
var my_timer;
$(".item").hover(
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text('Mouse-Over');
        clearTimeout(my_timer);
        $this.stop().fadeTo(250, 1);
    },
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.text('Mouse-Out');
        my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.fadeTo(250, 0);
        }, 500);
    }                       
);
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e3cNK/2/

Answer (score 13):

`.hide()` without any arguments doesn't use the effects queue (and won't have to wait for `.delay()`). Instead, you could use `$(this).delay(500).hide(0);`

Comment: This is perhaps the simplest way to do it. Just tried it, and seems to work like a charm! 

Still don't understand why .hide() .show() don't seem to work without an argument, which is weird! But thanks for the solution!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer!  It works only if you queue hide with a number.

Comment: This is some good information about the argument being passed. Be aware that this isn't hover-intent, it's always going to hide the element even if you re-hover it, you can add `.stop()` just before the `.show()` call to make it into hover-intent: http://jsfiddle.net/e3cNK/51/