# Dropdown menu needs to stay open after .hover

Tags: jquery

Ok, so I have tried so many things and nothing seems to be working. I would like the dropdown menu to stay open for a few seconds after the user has hovered over it (which I'm thinking will cause usability issues), how can I make this work with my current code?

```
$(".dropdown .sub").hover(function () {
     $("#menu .holder").show();
});
```

Comment: Can you share what you tried with a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) please ?  From what you just posted, there is no reason your menu would disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer : [Add delay before .hide() w/jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610800/add-delay-before-hide-w-jquery)

```
var my_timer;
$(".item").hover(
    function () {
        clearTimeout(my_timer);
        $(this).show();
    }, 
    function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $this.hide();
        }, 500);
    }                       
);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work for some reason:
           var my_timer;
           $(".dropdown .sub").hover(function () {
                clearTimeout(my_timer);
               $("#menu .holder").show();
            },
            function () {
              var $this = $(this);
              my_timer = setTimeout(function () {
                  $this.hide();
              }, 500);
          }

Comment: I answered my own question:           $('.dropdown .sub').mouseleave(function() {
            $('#menu .holder').delay( 800 ).slideUp( 400 );
        });