# How to Make An Element Close After 3 Seconds

Tags: jquery, hide, settimeout

Hello to anyone viewing this post!

My issue is as described below.

I have a message popup that pops up under what ever php event I'd like to display a message for. The only issue I am having is getting this message popup to close after 3 seconds.

Any help would be great! Thanks in advance!

I have also searched Google and the forums here at StackOverflow and the closest I could come to my issue was here: [Closing popup window after 3 seconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16127115/closing-popup-window-after-3-seconds) but even fiddling with this code I was unable to get things working the way I'd like them to.

My Code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   // jQuery
   $(document).ready(function() {
     var popup = document.getElementById("msgpop");
     popup.classList.toggle("show");
   });
   </script>
```

This don't seem to work.

```
setTimeout(window.close(), function(), 3000);
```

Comment: Sorry to waste anyone's time, I answered my own question. I needed to add a hide class in my css.

Comment: In that case, please delete your question so there is no wasted time by future readers.

Comment: This is a duplicate question on SO and should be deleted.  You can spare the moderators the job of closing it by deleting it yourself.  You could have searched SO using `[jquery] hide element after 3 seconds` and found your answer somewhere in the top four results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add delay before .hide() w/jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8610800/add-delay-before-hide-w-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

If toggling the class `"show"` is how you show the popup then presumably toggling the same class would be how you hide it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var popup = document.getElementById("msgpop");
  popup.classList.toggle("show");
  setTimeout(function() {
    popup.classList.toggle("show");
  }, 3000);
});
```

Regarding your code, this:

```
setTimeout(window.close(), function(), 3000);
```

...doesn't work for a few reasons. Firstly, `function()` is a syntax error. Secondly, you don't want to close the `window`, you just want to hide/close the popup element, so you don't want `window.close()`. Thirdly, even if you did want `window.close()`, your code would call that function *immediately* and pass its return value to `setTimeout()`. You need to pass a function to `setTimeout()`, like this:

```
setTimeout(functionName, 3000) // note no parentheses after functionName
```

...or to run a single line of code after the timeout you can wrap it in an anonymous function as shown above.

Comment: Yes you are 100% correct, some how in one of my edits I left out the hide in my css file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the css I needed to add.

```
.msgpop .hide {
visibility: invisible;
-webkit-animation: fadeOut 1s;
animation: fadeOut 1s
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` has only 2 parameter :D

I'm sure you actually want to:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.close(); }, 3000);
```